# Attach a PDF File to a Print Dialog

Tags: wpf, pdf, printdialog

I'm trying to attach a PDF File to a Print Dialog, but I haven't find out the way to do it.

I'm using a WPF app, and I have some code related with printing and looks like this:

```
private void Imprimir() 
    {
        try
        {
            FixedDocument document = null;
            PageContent pageContent = null;
            FixedPage fixedPage = null;

            PrintDialog printDlg = new PrintDialog();
            if (printDlg.ShowDialog() != true)
                return;
            document.DocumentPaginator.PageSize = new System.Windows.Size(1400, 1450);
            fixedPage.Width = document.DocumentPaginator.PageSize.Width;
            fixedPage.Height = document.DocumentPaginator.PageSize.Height;
            fixedPage.Margin = new Thickness(96, 96, 0, 0);
            fixedPage.Children.Add(this);

            ((System.Windows.Markup.IAddChild)pageContent).AddChild(fixedPage);
            document.Pages.Add(pageContent);
            printDlg.PrintDocument(document.DocumentPaginator, "Impresion Cierre");
            fixedPage.Children.Clear();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

But, by this way I'm just printing a UI Element added to Fixed Page.
I've looked for other codes, but I find nothing. 
So, I don´t know if is possible to add a PDF File stored locally to the Print Dialog ?

Thanks for the help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you cannot do this using PrintDialog. There are several options, depending on your goals:

```
        var printQueue = LocalPrintServer.GetDefaultPrintQueue();
        using (var input = File.OpenRead("path_to_your.pdf")) {
            using (var job = printQueue.AddJob()) {
                using (var output = job.JobStream) {
                    input.CopyTo(output);
                }
            }
        }
```

Will silently send print job for your file to local print queue. Print job is configurable.

Alternatively you can use adobe reader to handle that for you (or another pdf reader installed on user's machine) but starting process with path to your pdf as FileName and Verb="print".

One more option is to use third party tools (like ghostscript) which can help you with that.

Comment: Well, That I really need is to get the PDF File, then show a Print Dialog wich have to contain the PDF, so the user will have to choose printer and finally print this document...